# Text to speech in flex

Tags: apache-flex

is there any possible Text to speech in flex
Note: The voice wont go to another text to Speech website(example google translate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use system narrator/VoiceOver from Flex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021112/use-system-narrator-voiceover-from-flex)

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to prepare your input within Flex/Flash and then use AIR (local machine file access) or Flash Player Alchemy (In a nutshell: Adapter for C/C++ into Flash Player) to talk to a service that does what Flash cannot do, in this case it would be speech synthesis.

One such service would be the Microsoft Speech API. If you pull this off, this be some pretty cool sh!t

[Speech SDK 5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10121)